# How to show the label in BarLegend in Degree

Tags: plotting, legending

I would like to get label in `BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {-Pi/2, Pi/2}}]` to be from `-90 °` to `90 °`. Kindly see figure below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ticks = Transpose@{Range[-90, 90, 45], Range[-90 Degree, 90 Degree, 45 Degree]};

legend = BarLegend[{ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", {-90, 90}}], {-90, 90}},
          Charting`Ticks -> ticks]
```

[image]

Comment: I am using Mathematica 10, but this is not working. It gives the right label   but without color inside the barlegend

Comment: I am using Mathematica 10, but this is not working. It gives the right label but without color inside the barlegend. @corey979

Comment: @Abdullah I'm using v10.4.1 and apparently it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {-90 Degree, 90 Degree}}, 
 "Ticks" -> Range[-80 Degree, 80 Degree, 20 Degree]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]